# How do you update JLabels within a clicking game?

Tags: jlabel

I'm in a Programming and Problem Solving 1 class and this lab that we have is giving me a bit of trouble. Our professor has written out the bare bones code for the game "Cookie Clicker" and has asked us to fill in the rest to make the game actually work (if you aren't already familiar with the game, you most likely will not be able to help). As of now, the game has all the buttons already but if you click any of them, nothing happens. If anybody could show me how to update the JLabels so that the buttons show the correct numbers each time they're clicked, it'd be greatly appreciated. The part that needs the code is marked by //Start and //End, almost all the way at the bottom.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class CookieClickerGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
//Instance variables
public int cookies;
public int cursors;
public int grandmas;
public int farms;
public int factories;

//Getters
public int getCookies()
{
    return cookies;
}

public int getCursors()
{
    return cursors;
}

public int getGrandmas()
{
    return grandmas;
}

public int getFarms()
{
    return farms;
}

public int getFactories()
{
    return factories;
}

//Setters
public void setCookies()
{
    this.cookies = cookies;
}

public void setCursors()
{
    this.cursors = cursors;
}

public void setGrandmas()
{
    this.grandmas = grandmas;
}

public void setFarms()
{
    this.farms = farms;
}

public void setFactories()
{
    this.factories = factories;
}

/**
 * Creates new form CookieClickerGUI
 */
public CookieClickerGUI() {
    initComponents();
    cookieUpdater();
}
public void cookieUpdater() {
    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            //here is your action
            //update your cookies 
        }
    };
    Timer displayTimer = new Timer(1000, listener);
    displayTimer.start();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
private void initComponents() {

    cookieButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    numberOfCookiesLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    cursorButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    grandmaButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    farmButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    factoryButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    helperLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    grandmaLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    farmsLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    factoriesLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    helperCostLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    grandmaCostLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    farmsCostLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    factoriesCostLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);

    cookieButton.setText("Cookie");
    cookieButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cookieButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("Cookies:");

    numberOfCookiesLabel.setText("0");

    cursorButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cursorButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    grandmaButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            grandmaButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    farmButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            farmButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    factoryButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            factoryButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel2.setText("Number of Helpers:");

    helperLabel.setText("0");

    jLabel4.setText("Number of Grandmas:");

    grandmaLabel.setText("0");

    jLabel6.setText("Number of Farms:");

    farmsLabel.setText("0");

    jLabel8.setText("Number of Factories:");

    factoriesLabel.setText("0");

    jLabel3.setText("Cost:");

    jLabel5.setText("Cost:");

    jLabel7.setText("Cost:");

    jLabel9.setText("Cost:");

    helperCostLabel.setText("0");

    grandmaCostLabel.setText("0");

    farmsCostLabel.setText("0");

    factoriesCostLabel.setText("0");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(numberOfCookiesLabel))
                .addComponent(cookieButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(cursorButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(helperLabel))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(helperCostLabel))))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(grandmaButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(grandmaLabel))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(grandmaCostLabel))))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(farmButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel6)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(farmsLabel))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel7)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(farmsCostLabel))))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(factoryButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel8)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(factoriesLabel))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel9)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(factoriesCostLabel)))))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(numberOfCookiesLabel))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(cursorButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                .addComponent(helperLabel))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addComponent(helperCostLabel))))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(grandmaButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                .addComponent(grandmaLabel))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                .addComponent(grandmaCostLabel)))))
                .addComponent(cookieButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(farmButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6)
                        .addComponent(farmsLabel))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel7)
                        .addComponent(farmsCostLabel))))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(factoryButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel8)
                        .addComponent(factoriesLabel))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel9)
                        .addComponent(factoriesCostLabel))))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

//Start
private void cookieButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_cookieButtonActionPerformed
    cookies = cookies + 1;

}//GEN-LAST:event_cookieButtonActionPerformed

private void cursorButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_cursorButtonActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}//GEN-LAST:event_cursorButtonActionPerformed

private void grandmaButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_grandmaButtonActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}//GEN-LAST:event_grandmaButtonActionPerformed

private void farmButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_farmButtonActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}//GEN-LAST:event_farmButtonActionPerformed

private void factoryButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_factoryButtonActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}//GEN-LAST:event_factoryButtonActionPerformed

//End
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CookieClickerGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CookieClickerGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CookieClickerGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CookieClickerGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new CookieClickerGUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
private javax.swing.JButton cookieButton;
private javax.swing.JButton cursorButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel factoriesCostLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel factoriesLabel;
private javax.swing.JButton factoryButton;
private javax.swing.JButton farmButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel farmsCostLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel farmsLabel;
private javax.swing.JButton grandmaButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel grandmaCostLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel grandmaLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel helperCostLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel helperLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
private javax.swing.JLabel numberOfCookiesLabel;
// End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
```

}